# Android: How Can I apply transparency to ImageView with dark background

Tags: android, imageview, transparency

I have an imageview that is tranparent (See through), I want this to apply all the time except some scenarios which I want the transparency to have dark background (to Prevent See thru). How can I get dark background on transparent image?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimg_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

/>

Comment: While `you can make an opaque picture transparent`, you **can't do the opposite**. So, simply use **2** images.

Comment: Are you sure that I can't somehow make the background darker by playing with alpha or something?

Comment: Darker, yes, but not more opaque. You can try playing with ColorMatrices, for that.